# Access array values in a vector<Point2f> and separate x- and y coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a code which calculates the optical flow with the iterative Lucas-Kanade method: `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`.
I have a vector of an array that can hold two elements, see example below:

```
vector <Point2f> points[2];
```

The x and y coordinates are stored in the array and the array is stored in the vector. When outputting the array, for instance `cout << points[0]`, the coordinates are currently displayed on the screen as follows:

```
Output example: [261.837, 65.093]
```

Now I want to extract the x- and y coordinate, separate them and store them in different variables. Already tried several ways with an iterator with no result. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this, thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want to store in `points`? An array of vector is hardly the best solution.

Comment: I want to store the image x-y coordinates in points and be able to extract them separately. There are of course better and smarter ways to do this, but I haven't found this out yet.

Comment: Could you post your code? Is hard to find out a good solution without knowing your actual needs

Answer (score 2):

The following example applies the PLK to a regular grid and shows how to read the x and y coordinates. The points are stored in a Point2f class using the vector class to store them in an array. The class has public x and y members you can use directly. This examples uses no iterator.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> prevPoints, currPoints;
std::vector<float> error; // stores the SSD error. 
std::vector<uchar> status;// stores a flag of successful tracking / I recomend to ignore it.
cv::Mat prevGrayImg,currGrayImg;
// <- insert code for read the images
// initalize grid or the features you want to track
for( int r = 0; r < prevGrayImg.rows;r+=5){
for( int c = 0; c < prevGrayImg.cols;c+=5){
  prevPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(c,r));
}}
// apply pyramidal lucas kanade
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGrayImg, currGrayImg, prevPoints, currPoints, status, error);
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < prevPoints.size(); i++){
  float x0 = prevPoints[i].x;
  float y0 = prevPoints[i].y;
  float x1 = currPoints[i].x;
  float y1 = currPoints[i].y;
}
```

With iterator it would be:

```
for( auto i = prevPoints.begin(); i != prevPoints.end(); ++i){
  float x0 = i->x; ... a.s.o
```